# How to achieve security and hiding code from unauthorized user on web page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I'm creating a statistics web page which can see sensitive information.

The webpage has a sort of table which has massive data in it, editable and stored in Server's database. But It needs to be hidden before the user got proper authentications(Like log-in). (Table itself and it's code too). But I found that most of the questions in stack overflow say it is basically impossible. But when I see lots of well-known websites, it seems they are hiding them well. So I guess there are some solutions to the problem.

At first, I build a full-stack of React - Express - Node - MariaDB toolchain.

The `react client` is responsible for rendering contents of a webpage and editable tables and request for submitting edited content.

The `node with express` are responsible for retrieving data from DB, updating DB (Provides data to manipulate from client-side -- that's all)

It comes to a problem when I'm considering security on client-side code. I want to hide all content of the page (not just data from the server, but also its logic and features)

To achieving my goals, I consider several things, but I doubt if it is right and working well if I create.

1. Using Serverside rendering -- Cannot use due to performance reason and lack of resources available

   - Serverside rendering can hide logic from the user cause it omits the only HTML from the server and all actions are submitted to the server and the server handle the actions and provide its result.
   - So I can provide only the login page at first, and if login is successful, I can send the rest of HTML and it's logics from the server.
   - The problem is that my content in the webpage is massive and will be interacted with the user very often, and applying virtualization on my table (by performance reason), it's data and rendering logic should be handled by the web browser.
2. Combining SSR and Client-Side Rendering

   - My inspection for this is not sure, I doubt if it is possible.
   - Use SSR for hiding content of the site from unauthorized users, and if authorized, the web browser renders its full content on demand. (Code and logics should be hidden before authorization, the unauthorized user only can see the login page)
   - Is it possible to do it?
3. Get code on demand.

   - Also my inspection, this is what I am looking for. But I strongly doubt if it is possible.
   - Workflow is like below
     If a user is not logged in:: User only can see the login page and its code
     If the user is logged in:: User can see features of the page like management, statistics, etc.
     If the user approaches specific features:: Rendering logic and HTTP request interface is downloaded from the server (OR less-performance hindering logic or else...) and it renders what users want to see and do.

It is okay not to find ways from the above idea. Can you provide some outlines for implement such kind of web page? I'm quite new to Web Programming, so I cannot find proper ways. I want to know how can I achieve this with what kinds of solutions, library, structure.

What lib or package should I use for this?
How can I implement this?

OR can you describe to me how modern websites achieve this? (I think the SAP system quite resembles with what I wanna achieve)

Comment: The data from your API (Rest, GraphQL or anything else) can be protected by token or credential authentication, preventing accessing anything sensitive if the user isn't logged in. I do believe something can be done with WebPack and entrypoints setup to load parts of the application independently. Though, if I may ask, why would you go through the hurdle of hiding the logic of the application ?

Comment: To expand, I would recommend having a look at WebPack's entrypoint, notably the [multipage application](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#multi-page-application), you would need to tweak a few things in the optimisaiton module, so you don't have code that is repeated between the different parts though. I can put together an answer if needed, but some people might have better understanding than me.

Comment: @PierreChevallier Really appreciate your answer. I skimmed entrypoint in webpack, it seems like it is some sort of splitting main functions if I compare to C language. (Not accurate in fact) Am I right? And if using this, where should I put the codes Back Server or Client? It is quite reasonable when I checked entrypoint. Regarding second question, it is requirement for the program unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Foreword

*Security is a complex topic, in which it is not possible to reach 0 threat. I'll try to craft an answer that could fullfil what you are looking for.*

## Back end: Token, credentials, authentication

So, you are currently using Express for your back end, hence the need to sort of protect the access from this part, many solution exist, I favor the [token authentication](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/02/14/modern-token-authentication-in-node-with-express), but you can do something with [username/password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035264/node-js-username-and-password-authentication) (or [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_authentication.htm)) to let the users access the back end.

From what you are describing you would use some sort of API ([REST](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_restful_api.htm), [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/running-an-express-graphql-server/) etc.) to connect to the back-end and make your queries ([fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch), [cross-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-fetch), [apollo-link](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link) etc.) and add the token to the call to the back end in the headers usually.

If a user doesn't have the proper token, they have no data. Many sites use that method to block the consumption of data from the users (e.g. Twitter, Instagram). This should cover the security of the data for your back end, and no code is exposed.

## Front-end: WebPack and application code splitting

Now the tricky part, so you want the client side not to have access to all the front-end at once but in several parts. This has 2 caveats:

1. It will be a bit slower than in normal use
2. Once the client logged in once, he will have access to the application

The only workaround I see in this situation is to use only server side rendering, if you want to limit to the bare minimum the amount of data the client has on your front end. Granted it is slow, but if you want maximum protection that is the only solution.

Yet, if you want to still keep some interactions and have a faster front end, while keeping a bit of security, you could use some code splitting with WebPack. I am not familiar with C so I can't say, but the [Multiple page application](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#multi-page-application.) of WebPack, as I was mentionning in the comment, should give you a good start to build something more secure.

First, you would have for example 2 `html` files for entering the front end: one with the login and one with the application. The login contains only the Javascript modules that are for entering the application and shouldn't load the other Javascript modules.

All in all, entrypoints are the way you can enter the application, this is a very broad topic that I can't cover in this answer, but I would recommend you to follow [WebPack's tutorial](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) and find out how you can work this out.
I recommend the part on code splitting, but all the tutorial is worth having a look.

Second, you will have to tweak the optimisation module. It is usually a module that tries to reduce the size of the application by merging methods that are used by different parts or that are redundant: **you don't want this**.

In your case, you don't want un-authenticated users to have access. So you would have to probably change things there (as well another broad topic to be covered in a single answer, since you would have to decide what you keep for optimisation and what you remove for security), but here is the link to the [optimisation module](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/) and a heads up, you will have to modify the `SplitChunksPlugin` not to do this optimisation.

*I hope this helps, there are many solutions are hand and this is not a comprehensive guide but that should give you enough materials to get to what you need.*

Comment: I considered SSR for hiding codes. But it is deadly slow and I think it will block implementing complicated logic. So I removed it from my consideration. Regarding solution which working with webpack is seems like really reasonable. I need to look up tutorials for them. Yet, I wonder if webpack really can make this work but this is my responsibility. I really appreciate for your helps.